# ansible lineinfile based on conditionals

Tags: ansible

I am having the following playbook in ansible where "{{env}}" is a dynamic variable: could be sit,nft,prod,etc - based on user selection. The action in the play should be executed only if the selected environment is nft.

```
- hosts: "{{ host }}"
  remote_user: "{{ user }}"

  vars:
    home_dir: "/home/{{ user }}"
    env: "{{ env }}"

  tasks:
    - name: backup file
      copy:
        src: "/home/dtcd/gabi/FF_environmentConfig.ini"
        dest: "/home/dtcd/gabi/FF_environmentConfig.ini_orig"
        remote_src: yes

    - name: change params nft
      lineinfile:
        path: "/home/dtcd/gabi/FF_environmentConfig.ini"
        regexp: '{{item.From}}'
        line: '{{item.To}}'
        state: present
      with_items:
        - { From: 'FF_AMQProcessingMessageTimeoutInMilliseconds=5000', To: 'FF_AMQProcessingMessageTimeoutInMilliseconds=10000' }
        - { From: 'FF_solutionDetectionServiceProcess_FF_ALL_FF_customFeedChannel_ConcurrentThreads=1', To: 'FF_solutionDetectionServiceProcess_FF_ALL_FF_customFeedChannel_ConcurrentThreads=10' }
      when: env == nft
```

Now, when I am running the playbook, it errors out with the message:

> fatal: [servera.com]: FAILED! => {
> "msg": "The conditional check 'env == nft' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (env == nft): 'nft' is
> undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in
> '/ansible-playbook/1-sed.yml': line 15,
> column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact
> syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name:
> change params nft\n      ^ here\n" }

I have tried using when: "{{env}}" == "nft", using set_facts... but in the end I am still facing the error above.

Using set_facts I was able to overcome the error, however the actions were skipped, despite env=nft.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `when: env == "nft"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write:

```yaml
      when: env == nft
```

You are saying: "When the value of the variable `env` matches the value of the variable `nft`".

Ansible is telling you that you have no variable named `nft` (`'nft' is undefined`), which is accurate.

If you want to compare a variable to a *literal string*, you need to quote the string:

```yaml
      when: env == "nft"
```

Comment: Apparently, when I tried that, one "=" was missing from the check and it did not worked. Tried it again now and worked. Thank you!